# how to get the list of Function and Sub of a given module name in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a helper macro that look into the list function on a given module name on the active excel workbook.
Ex: I have a module name "Module1". Inside this module has the following function or sub

```
Sub Sub1()
End Sub

Sub Sub2()
End Sub

Function Func1()
End Function

Function Func2()
End Function
```

Is there a command or routine that can return the list of Function and Sub names?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a link to Chip Pearson's site. This is where I go whenever I need to program something that affects or uses the VBE. There are 2 sections that might interest you. One will list all modules in a project. And another will list all procedures in a module. Hope that helps.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Code from the site (make sure to visit the site for instructions on adding a reference to the VBIDE object library:

This code will list all the procedures in Module1, beginning the listing in cell A1.

```
Sub ListProcedures()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum As Long
    Dim NumLines As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim ProcName As String
    Dim ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Rng = WS.Range("A1")
    With CodeMod
        LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
        Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
            ProcName = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)
            Rng.Value = ProcName
            Rng(1, 2).Value = ProcKindString(ProcKind)
            LineNum = .ProcStartLine(ProcName, ProcKind) + _
                    .ProcCountLines(ProcName, ProcKind) + 1
            Set Rng = Rng(2, 1)
        Loop
    End With

End Sub

Function ProcKindString(ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind) As String
    Select Case ProcKind
        Case vbext_pk_Get
            ProcKindString = "Property Get"
        Case vbext_pk_Let
            ProcKindString = "Property Let"
        Case vbext_pk_Set
            ProcKindString = "Property Set"
        Case vbext_pk_Proc
            ProcKindString = "Sub Or Function"
        Case Else
            ProcKindString = "Unknown Type: " & CStr(ProcKind)
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: For those who struggled like me to find the library to import, go to Tools-> References and check "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3".

Comment: Thank you so much for that, @Takichiii! I would never have gotten this really useful code to work without your help.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a free tool called "MZ-Tools". Install it as an add-in, It numbers your lines of code, generates standard error management code, checks unused variables, orders your functions and sub and ... documents your code, by automatically generating a list of your procedures with parameters, comments, etc.... A great tool!

Answer (score 2):

For those looking for a function returning a collection of Strings, here is some code adapted from guitarthrower's answer:

```
'Collection of Strings of Sub names in that module
Private Function getAllProcNames(module As VBIDE.CodeModule) As Collection
    Dim lineNum As Integer
    Dim procName As String
    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind
    With module
        lineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
        Do Until lineNum >= .CountOfLines
            procName = .ProcOfLine(lineNum, ProcKind)
            lineNum = .ProcStartLine(procName, ProcKind) + _
                    .ProcCountLines(procName, ProcKind) + 1
            coll.Add Item:=procName
        Loop
    End With
    Set getAllProcNames = coll
End Function
```

The ProcKind variable is just thrown away- this gives names only.

Answer (score 1):

```
' a bit more info for those who like me looking for help
' without Chip Pearson and many others my programming would still be at
' x=x+4

    Option Explicit
'
' to list or sort procedure names
'
'
' on a spare sheet
'
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim URA$, RaSort As Range, ModName$, VBC As VBComponent

   Dim RangeStartAddress$: RangeStartAddress = "H11" ' any spare region

   Set RaSort = Range(RangeStartAddress)

   ' sort and display needs 5 un-bordered columns so best done from spare worksheet

   RaSort(0, 0).Resize(UsedRange.Rows.Count, 7).Clear
   URA = UsedRange.Address                 ' tidy of used range

   ModName = [c6]

   ' from cell C4 ... or whatever is needed name is needed

   ' OR ... to do all modules ... Skipping workbook try something like
   '
   'For Each VBC In ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents

     ' Range("G11:N" & UsedRange.Rows.Count).Clear

     ' URA = UsedRange.Address

     'Set RaSort = Range("h11")

      'If Not (VBC.Name Like "Workbook") Then

       ' SortSUBLGFUN VBC.Name, RaSort

      'End If

  ' Next VBC


   SortSUBLGFUN ModName, RaSort

End Sub
'
' in a module
'
' sort the procedure names  for a module

' Reference to VBE  ..    Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility

' RaSort as some spare Range CurrentRegion
'
Sub SortSUBLGFUN(ComponentName$, RaSort As Range)

   Dim LineI%, PBLI&, RowI&, RowOut&, LineStr$

   Dim PLSG As vbext_ProcKind              '  0 Fun or Sub 1 Let 2 Set 3 Get
   Dim ProcName$
   Dim StartLineI&, CountLinesI&, LinesOfProc$


   With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ComponentName).CodeModule

      LineI = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1

      While LineI < .CountOfLines
         PLSG = 0
         While PLSG < 3 And LineI < .CountOfLines ' look for all types

            On Error GoTo LookMore         ' msny may not exist

            ProcName = .ProcOfLine(LineI, PLSG)
            CountLinesI = .ProcCountLines(ProcName, PLSG)
            StartLineI = .ProcStartLine(ProcName, PLSG)

            RowOut = RowOut + 1
            RaSort(RowOut, 1) = ProcName
            RaSort(RowOut, 2) = PLSG
            RaSort(RowOut, 3) = StartLineI
            RaSort(RowOut, 4) = CountLinesI


            ' the procedure can have blanks or comment lines at the top
            ' so start line is not always the Procedure body line
            ' the  ProcBodyLine may be extended for over  about 20 lines
            ' using the  line-continuation char  " _"
            ' so it looks a bit complex to find the actual line

            PBLI = .ProcBodyLine(ProcName, PLSG)
            LineStr = .Lines(PBLI, 1)
            While Right(LineStr, 2) = " _" ' if extended get the other lines
               PBLI = PBLI + 1
               LineStr = Left(LineStr, Len(LineStr) - 2) & " " & .Lines(PBLI, 1)
            Wend

            RaSort(RowOut, 5) = LineStr

            LineI = StartLineI + CountLinesI + 1
            If LineI > .CountOfLines Then PLSG = 14 ' > 3
LookMore:

            On Error GoTo 0
            PLSG = PLSG + 1
         Wend

         LineI = LineI + 1
      Wend
      Set RaSort = RaSort.CurrentRegion
      RaSort.Sort RaSort(1, 1), xlAscending
      '
      'bring each to the top  from Z to A results in  sorted alphabetically
      '
      For RowI = RaSort.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

         ProcName = RaSort(RowI, 1)
         PLSG = RaSort(RowI, 2)
         '
         ' since they have moved need to refind them before moving to top
         '
         CountLinesI = .ProcCountLines(ProcName, PLSG)
         StartLineI = .ProcStartLine(ProcName, PLSG)

         LinesOfProc = .Lines(StartLineI, CountLinesI)
         .DeleteLines StartLineI, CountLinesI
         .InsertLines .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1, LinesOfProc
      Next RowI
   End With


End Sub

'
' you may find the two below of interest
'
Sub TabsAscending()

   Dim I&, J&

   For I = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count

      For J = 1 To Application.Sheets.Count - 1

         If UCase$(Application.Sheets(J).Name) > UCase$(Application.Sheets(J + 1).Name) then
            Sheets(J).Move after:=Sheets(J + 1)
         End If
      Next J
   Next I
End Sub

Sub ResetCodeNames(WkWb As Workbook)

  'Changes the codename conventional name  gets rid of Sheet3 Sheet7 where they have been given a name


   Dim VarItem  As VBIDE.VBComponent

   For Each VarItem In WkWb.VBProject.VBComponents

   'Type 100 is a worksheet

   If VarItem.Type = 100 And VarItem.Name <> "ThisWorkbook" Then

       VarItem.Name = VarItem.Properties("Name").Value

    End If

 Next

End Sub

' hope it helps others
```