# In MS Project how can I list all the sub routines along with their module names

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a reasonable number of macros which are grouped by modules in a seperate MSP file. I use this as my repository of useful macros.

I aim to re-use a sub routine in another one (as is good practice) but I spend a bit of time hunting through the modules for the macro I know exists.

It would be very useful to have a list of routines, with their Modules, so that I know where they live and can easily use "call module.sub" to call them into the current code.

I've had a look and can't find this and I have no idea how to even start :)

Thanks in advance for any pointers or code you can share.

UPDATE:
Following the excellent links from Chill60 and Rachael I cames cross some similar code which I was able to adapt to my needs.  I enclose this code in the hope it will be useful to someone in the future:

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose   :       Prints all subs and functions in a project
' Prerequisites:    Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 library
'                   CreateLogFile
' How to run:       Run GetFunctionAndSubNames, set a parameter to blnWithParentInfo
'                   If ComponentTypeToString(vbext_ct_StdModule) = "Code Module" Then
'
' Used:             ComponentTypeToString from -> http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'taken from https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-listing-all-procedures-in-all-modules/
'slight modiications to display the module names and customise for MS Project rather than Excel
'changed CreateLogFile to Debug.print
'added choice of how to display the modules

Option Explicit

Private strSubsInfo As String
Public Sub X_GetFunctionAndSubNames()
 
    Dim item            As Variant
    strSubsInfo = ""
    Dim displaychoice As Integer
    
    displaychoice = InputBox("How do you want to display the module names?:" & vbCrLf & "1 = In line with the Procedure Names, seperated by a ':'" & vbCrLf & "2 = The Module name: and then the Procedure names under the Module")
    If Not (displaychoice = 1 Or displaychoice = 2) Then
        MsgBox ("Only 1 or 2 can be chosen, the code will now exit")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For Each item In ThisProject.VBProject.VBComponents 'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
        
        If ComponentTypeToString(vbext_ct_StdModule) = "Code Module" Then
            ListProcedures item.Name, displaychoice, False
 
            
            'Debug.Print item.CodeModule.Lines(1, item.CodeModule.CountOfLines)
        End If
        
    Next item
    Debug.Print strSubsInfo
    Clipboard (strSubsInfo)
    MsgBox ("The procedure and module names have been printed to the Immediate window and has been saved to the Clipboard")
    'CreateLogFile strSubsInfo
End Sub

Private Sub ListProcedures(strName As String, displaychoice As Integer, Optional blnWithParentInfo = False)

    'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3 library is needed for this to run.

    Dim VBProj          As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp          As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod         As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim LineNum         As Long
    Dim ProcName        As String
    Dim ModuleName As String
    Dim ProcKind        As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind
   

    Set VBProj = ThisProject.VBProject  'ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(strName)
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
    ModuleName = VBComp.CodeModule.Name
    
    If displaychoice = 2 Then strSubsInfo = strSubsInfo & IIf(strSubsInfo = vbNullString, vbNullString, vbCrLf) & "Module - " & ModuleName
    
    With CodeMod
        LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
        
        Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
            ProcName = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)

            If blnWithParentInfo Then
                If displaychoice = 2 Then strSubsInfo = strSubsInfo & IIf(strSubsInfo = vbNullString, vbNullString, vbCrLf) & strName & "." & ProcName
                If displaychoice = 1 Then strSubsInfo = strSubsInfo & IIf(strSubsInfo = vbNullString, vbNullString, vbCrLf) & strName & "." & ProcName & " : " & ModuleName
            Else
                If displaychoice = 2 Then strSubsInfo = strSubsInfo & IIf(strSubsInfo = vbNullString, vbNullString, vbCrLf) & ProcName
                If displaychoice = 1 Then strSubsInfo = strSubsInfo & IIf(strSubsInfo = vbNullString, vbNullString, vbCrLf) & ProcName & " : " & ModuleName
            End If

            LineNum = .ProcStartLine(ProcName, ProcKind) + .ProcCountLines(ProcName, ProcKind) + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub

Function ComponentTypeToString(ComponentType As VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType) As String
    'ComponentTypeToString from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx
    Select Case ComponentType
    
        Case vbext_ct_ActiveXDesigner
            ComponentTypeToString = "ActiveX Designer"
            
        Case vbext_ct_ClassModule
            ComponentTypeToString = "Class Module"
            
        Case vbext_ct_Document
            ComponentTypeToString = "Document Module"
            
        Case vbext_ct_MSForm
            ComponentTypeToString = "UserForm"
            
        Case vbext_ct_StdModule
            ComponentTypeToString = "Code Module"
            
        Case Else
            ComponentTypeToString = "Unknown Type: " & CStr(ComponentType)
            
    End Select
    
End Function

Function Clipboard(Optional StoreText As String) As String
'PURPOSE: Read/Write to Clipboard
'Source: ExcelHero.com (Daniel Ferry)

Dim x As Variant

'Store as variant for 64-bit VBA support
  x = StoreText

'Create HTMLFile Object
  With CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With .parentWindow.clipboardData
      Select Case True
        Case Len(StoreText)
          'Write to the clipboard
            .setData "text", x
        Case Else
          'Read from the clipboard (no variable passed through)
            Clipboard = .GetData("text")
      End Select
    End With
  End With

End Function
```

Comment: Does Ctrl-F not work in MS-Project? Select "Current Project" for the scope of the search

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630872/how-to-get-the-list-of-function-and-sub-of-a-given-module-name-in-excel-vba

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the list of Function and Sub of a given module name in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630872/how-to-get-the-list-of-function-and-sub-of-a-given-module-name-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thank you Rachel and Chill60.  Those were very useful links.  I was trying to understand how some of it worked and during those searches I cam across this page:  https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-listing-all-procedures-in-all-modules/ which usese some similar code.  I was able to adapt it and solve the issue.  Can I post the code as a follow up in some way?